# create a Menu that stays an loads page under it

Tags: html, iframe, menu

My Problem is this, I am trying to create a Menu, for my web site.
what i need to do is have the menu always stay on at the top of every page an not load into the same Iframe. I have tried Iframe but all it does is load the index page well'; but if i click on a menu item it loads the next page inside the iframe, not what i need.
WHAT YOU SEE BELOW IS NOT LIVE, it is only my test page inside DreamWeaver.

I have also tried a dropdown menu with bad results. I am using the base.html, so this way I do not have to edit 25 other page menus but use one for all.
please help Im loosing my mind here.

If there is something else i can try, Please let me know, thank you so much.
P.S. Kinda NEW to this, worked with Frontpage 20 years ago. just now getting back into this.

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="DreamWeaver 2021">
<title>Welcome to the Ohiopowmia.com Website</title>
    <body background="images/powmiabg.jpg">
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.ohiopowmia.org/base.html" target="_parent"style="border:none;" height="320" width="100%" title="Main Menu">
</iframe>
    <font size="5"><b>WE'RE BACK!!!!!!!!!</b></font></p>
<p align="center" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><b>
In 2007 Ohiopowmia.com went offline, we had some issues with the host, and then the I lost my full time employment and was unable to keep the site.  After much debate we decided against letting someone else take over the site, and with the feeling we could not keep up the site and do it justice, we would allow the site to disappear from the web.  We have tried over the years to reopen the site but we could not keep it managed.<br><br>
On Dec 1st, 2020 the sites inspiration, Marilyn Grote, passed away leaving a empty space in all of our lives.  I decided as a way to honor her and what she stood for I was going to reopen, and maintain, this site once and for all in her memory and the memory of all the hero's who did not come home!.<br><br>
    <BR>
        <img src="images/mom.jpg" height="300" width="300"> <BR><BR>
        With the help of the sites new President, Richard, over the next few weeks/months you will see a completely redone site and we will strive to keep updates on here as much as possible.  Please be patient with us as we begin to get the site back up to it’s full glory<BR> <BR>
</p>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

[IFRAME base.html top click on menu item load bottom but doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yza5n.png)

Comment: do you have a sample screenshot of what you're trying to achieve? possibly from another  site or something

Comment: added picture to top hope it helps. the top part is a HTML file called base.html. in iframe. loads the 3 pictures an teh menu, bottom loads the text i put in. but if you click on a menu item. it loads in the IFRAME not in the main window.

Comment: <font> is also 20 years old.... do not use font tags.

Comment: Your thinking of using frames really is old school. I would just find code that writes the menu on the page if you are not able to use serverside language t include it.

Comment: epascarello - I told you I haven't done this in 20 years, yes im using Iframes. I have looked for a code that does that an so far I cant find one or I just don't understand the new lingo, again haven't touched this in 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can add click event on one for the links in your iframe like

```
<a id="to-about-page">Pow/Mia Website</a>
```

and then in the js of your iframe

```
var toAbout = document.querySelector('#to-about-page');

toAbout.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var redirectUrl = 'some-url-you-want-to-go-to-in-your-parent-window.com';
  if (window.parent === window) {
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
  }
}
```

let me know if this works